# Linker fails after initialize Mixpanel library in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker-errors, mixpanel

I am working on a mobile app using Unity3D and Mixpanel. The app runs successfully on an iPhone6, after I import the Mixpanel library it fails in Xcode with the following message:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L@(inherited)'
ld: library not found for -lMixpanel
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
 invocation)
```

How can I fix this?